# Viewing activity-specific (gate-to-gate) environmental inventory

Tags: brightway

Just wondering if there is a way in Brightway to view gate-to-gate (direct) emissions of a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for exc in my_activity.biosphere():
    print(exc['amount'], exc.input, exc.output)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'm fascinated by Brightway and its power  and aiming to join next year's training course